# Node.js express server with compression not work

Tags: node.js, compression

From lighthouse chrome test page:

```
 URL                  Transfer Size                 Potential Savings
/three.module.min.js      630.3 KiB                   477.3 KiB
```

I minify but performance still need compression.

```js
...
function shouldCompress (req, res) {
  if (req.headers['x-no-compression']) {
    // don't compress responses with this request header
    return false
  }
 
  // fallback to standard filter function
  return compression.filter(req, res)
}

hostingHTTP.use(compression({ filter: shouldCompress }))
...
```

My request :

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,ru;q=0.8
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Host: maximumroulette.com
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: https://maximumroulette.com/apps/magic/public/module.html
sec-ch-ua: "Not_A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="109", "Chromium";v="109"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
Sec-Fetch-Dest: script
Sec-Fetch-Mode: no-cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

My response:

```
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: public, max-age=0
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 394590
Content-Type: application/javascript; charset=UTF-8
Date: Mon, 13 Feb 2023 20:39:00 GMT
ETag: W/"6055e-1864c7208a7"
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
Last-Modified: Mon, 13 Feb 2023 20:23:07 GMT
X-Powered-By: Express
```

Did i need some action onclietn part for decopression ?

If i setup on server  `res.set('Content-Encoding', 'deflate'); // gzip, deflate, br` a get error on chrome:

`net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED 200 (OK)`

Any suggestion ?